# Getting dynamic data from Json to Html with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, html

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ridge-speedometer']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('asd.php').then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData = 33; ////////// response.data
    });
};

// Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.
$scope.intervalFunction = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.getData();
        $scope.intervalFunction();
    }, 1000)
};

// Kick off the interval
$scope.intervalFunction();
```

Hi guys, as you see the codes above, I just have problem that line:

```
$scope.myData = 33; 
$scope.myData = response.data"
```

when I'm writing 33 to the variable it works, but with "response.data". It isn't working. How can I get the value of my JSON.

This is my JSON page

```
[{"value":"23"}]
```

I have to get this `23`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, You need to access the **`index[0]`** of the response

```
$scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('asd.php').then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data[0].value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.You have JSON response

```
[{"value":"23"}]
```

Get value

```
$scope.myData = response[0].value;
```

See Demo

```js
var response= '[{"value":"23"}]';
object = JSON.parse(response); //parses your json into object
console.log(object[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try get it with `response.data[0].value`.

Maybe you have to `JSON.parse(response.data)[0].value` to get it.

Answer (score -1):

In `$http` service calls , data response is usually in this format

[image]

I suggest you to get data like this

```
var response = response.data.data;

// now you can assign like you are doing
$scope.myData = response.value;

// or if your response is an array
$scope.myData = response[0].value;
```

I hope this helps. Thanks